# How do I find what program is sending an email from a linux server

Tags: linux, rhel, email

We have inherited a RHEL server and it is continually trying to send e-mails to defunct email aliases. Is there any way of finding out what program is sending the emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the contents of e-mails. If they are sent to defunct aliases, they should be stuck in queue. RHEL usually uses sendmail, so queued e-mails should be in `/var/spool/mqueue/`. Look for the content of files there. That should give you a clue, what is sending them.

There can be many programs that can send e-mails. It can be (ana)crontabs. Look into `/var/spool/cron/` to see what crontabs are running. It can be logwatch, or some other programs executed regularly. It can also be some daemon, although that is unlikely.

Comment: Excellent, that's done the trick. Looks like it was being generated from a script that was being invoked by the crontab which I've modified now so we'll see if any more shake out